# 400 (Bad Request) in image url angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
ImageUrl/{{product.thumb_vImage}} 400 (Bad Request)
```

I getting above error in my `console`; I want to know the reason of it.

```
<div class="img" ng-repeat="product in products| orderBy : sort_by |limitTo:limit track by $index " >
  <a ng-click="displayProduct(product)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_product"> 
      <img class="image_{{product.iProductID}}" src="{{product.thumb_vImage}}" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: use ng-src="{{}}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this use **`{{}}`** instead of **`[[]]`** also `ng-src` instead of **`src`**,

```
   <img class="image_{{product.iProductID}}" ng-src="{{product.thumb_vImage}}" alt="">
```